# Why are two mock child component instances created while running Angular unit tests?

Tags: angular, angular-test, viewchild

My Angular 13 application has the following:

- An app component that displays a welcome message and a parent component
- A parent component that displays some text and a child component inside a `div` and listens to the child component's selection changes, using `@ViewChild` to get the child component
- A child component that displays a `mat-select` and emits the user's selections via a private `EventEmitter` that is exposed through a public `Observable` output.

**When I run the app**, everything works. When I make a selection in the child component, the parent component gets the selection change as expected. But **when I run my parent component unit tests**, using a mock child component that has an RxJs `ReplaySubject` in place of the `EventEmitter` and `Observable`, the parent component does *not* get the expected selection change.

While investigating this behavior, I added some `console.log` statements and some unique object IDs to find out which components were getting created. I learned that one parent component instance is created, as expected, but *two different* mock child component instances are created! Worse, one of the child component instances is set as the parent component's `ViewChild` and available in `ngAfterViewInit`, but the other child component instance is returned in the parent test when querying `component.debugElement`. That means that when I artificially emit a selection change on the test's child component, the parent never sees it.

Look in the test output below and see that two mock child components are created. The test gets the component with ID 1 by querying the `debugElement`, but the parent component gets the component with ID 2 as its `ViewChild`. I only want there to be one mock child component.

Again, this is only a problem during unit testing. In the running app, only one child component instance is created, and everything works fine.

Why is Angular creating two mock child component instances during testing, and how can I force it to create just one?

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent/parent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<app-parent></app-parent>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'parent-child-test';
}
```

`parent.component.html`:

```
<div class="order-form">
    <h2>Order Form</h2>
    <div>
        <b>Flavor</b>
        <app-child></app-child>
    </div>
</div>
```

`parent.component.ts`:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent, Flavor, flavors } from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private static lastId = 0;// For testing

  readonly id: number;

  flavor: Flavor = flavors[0];

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
  private childComponent!: ChildComponent;

  constructor() {
    this.id = ++ParentComponent.lastId;
    console.log(`Created ${this.constructor.name} ${this.id}`);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(
      `In parent afterViewInit, child component ID is ${this.childComponent.id}`
    );
    this.childComponent.flavorChanged.subscribe(flavor => {
      console.log(`New flavor is ${flavor}. Everything seems to be working!`);
      this.flavor = flavor;
    });
  }

}
```

`parent.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ChildComponent, Flavor, flavors } from '../child/child.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '',
  providers: [
    { provide: ChildComponent, useClass: MockChildComponent }
  ]
})
class MockChildComponent {

  private static lastId = 0;// For testing

  readonly id: number;// For testing

  readonly flavorChanged = new ReplaySubject<Flavor>(1);

  constructor() {
    this.id = ++MockChildComponent.lastId;// For testing
    console.log(`Created ${this.constructor.name} ${this.id}`);
  }

}

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MockChildComponent, ParentComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should receive flavor when child component emits it', () => {
    let flavor: Flavor = flavors[0];

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.flavor).toEqual(flavor);

    flavor = flavors[flavors.length - 1];

    // I tried queryAll instead of query to see if I could get
    // more than one, but it only returned one, and this is it:
    const childComponent: MockChildComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.directive(ChildComponent)
    ).componentInstance;
    console.log(`In test, child component ID is ${childComponent.id}`);
    childComponent.flavorChanged.next(flavor);

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.flavor).toEqual(flavor);
  });
});
```

`child.component.html`:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="flavor">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let flavorOption of flavors" [value]="flavorOption">
        {{ flavorOption }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

`child.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

export const flavors = ['Chocolate', 'Strawberry', 'Vanilla'] as const;
export type Flavor = typeof flavors[number];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  private static lastId = 0;// For testing

  readonly id: number;// For testing

  readonly flavors = flavors;

  selectedFlavor: Flavor = flavors[0];

  private readonly flavorChangedEmitter = new EventEmitter<Flavor>();

  @Output()
  readonly flavorChanged = this.flavorChangedEmitter.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.id = ++ChildComponent.lastId;// For testing
    console.log(`Created ${this.constructor.name} ${this.id}`);
  }

  get flavor(): Flavor {
    return this.selectedFlavor as Flavor;
  }

  set flavor(newFlavor: Flavor) {
    this.selectedFlavor = newFlavor;

    this.flavorChangedEmitter.emit(newFlavor);
  }

}
```

Console messages when running the application and choosing a flavor (this is fine):

```
parent.component.ts:22 Created ParentComponent 1
child.component.ts:28 Created ChildComponent 1
parent.component.ts:26 In parent afterViewInit, child component ID is 1
parent.component.ts:28 New flavor is Vanilla. Everything seems to be working!
```

Test output (this doesn't work):

```
LOG: 'Created ParentComponent 1'
LOG: 'Created MockChildComponent 1'
LOG: 'Created MockChildComponent 2'
LOG: 'In parent afterViewInit, child component ID is 2'
LOG: 'In test, child component ID is 1'
Chrome 100.0.4896.75 (Windows 10) ParentComponent should receive flavor when child component emits it FAILED
        Error: Expected 'Chocolate' to equal 'Vanilla'.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/parent/parent.component.spec.ts:61:46)        
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)   
Chrome 100.0.4896.75 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 5 (1 FAILED) (skipped 4) (0.117 secs / 0.08 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
```

Comment: I realize now that I can skip mocking the child component and simply set its `flavor` property since it's a setter that calls the emitter. Facepalm moment. ‍♂️ Still, I think the question about why two child components are getting created is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, because you provide the service in `@Component`.

In that case, likewise for `@Directive`, for every new instance of the component, there will be new instances of its providers, which will be used in nested components / directives / pipes.

If you need to override a provider, simply override it in your `AppModule` or in `TestBed` for tests.